# Debug android app when screen off

Tags: android, debugging

I have a problem. I observed that when I want to DEBUG my Android application from Eclipse, and the device has the screen turned off and it is locked, then if I use these lines:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

this works, but the problem is that the Activity has the following lifecycle events:

```
onCreate()onResume()onPause()onResume()
```

And after that the screen is turned on and the app is running. But I don't need the pause there.

Comment: Is the call to onPause() causing some sort of trouble? Or do you aim to get rid of it simply because it is unneeded and doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yes, it is causing. I use GLSurfaceView, and Application states are processed inside it, like suggested in Beginning Android Games book, and in such case, the GLSurfaceView onDrawFrame method never gets called before the first onPause, and in onPause I have a wait on a lock, and the notify is inside the onDrawFrame, so application blocks. I can however insert a boolean in GLView to verify if the renderer was called at least once, but this is a hack...